# Eliminating cases with propositions in Coq

Tags: coq

Given an obvious definition of a natural number list type, and a function `last` that takes the last element or returns a default, I'm trying to prove the following lemma:

```
Lemma last_ignores_first : forall l : natlist, forall def n : nat,
  length l > 0 ->
  last def (n :: l) = last def l.
```

Now, I want to prove it by noting that since `l` is not empty, it must be able to be written in the form `h::t` for some `h` and `t`, and thus the proof will follow from the definition of `last`. But how can I use that knowledge in Coq? If I do `induction` or `destruct` on `l`, I will have to account for the case where `l` is `[]`, a case which is prevented by the hypothesis. How to I tell it that `l` must follow a certain form?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just have to use inversion on your hypothesis that states that `length l > 0`:

```
intros [|x l] def n H.
- (* Case l = [], contradiction *)
  simpl in H. inversion H.
- (* Continue normally *)
```

Comment: Thanks! I learned a little about inversion but I'm still new to it and don't fully understand it yet. That did work though :)